# Is there any alternative of SKStoreReviewController for AppleTV to allow user to submit app rating?

Tags: apple-tv, skstorereviewcontroller

I want user to rate my appleTV app for that I want to show them rating popup to the user as we show the popup on iOS app using SKStoreReviewController but it is not supported in AppleTV.